# Running Xposed inside Google Android Emulator with custom image

Tags: android, android-emulator, xposed

**Problem description:**

I need to get droidmon working on a specific android image with predefined parameters. Xposed framework shows an error on installation, that it requires root access.

**Environment:**

Google Android Emulator running a custom rooted Android 4.4.2 x86 image with kernel version 3.4.67+ (but i have the same problem with 3.10+)
Used parameters (+ extra params that have nothing to do with android itslef):

- -avd
- -kernel
- -ramdisk
- -no-cache
- -selinux permissive
- -no-snapstorage
- -verbose
- -show-kernel

SDK-Tools-Version: 25.2.2

SDK-Platform-Tools: 24.0.3

Android is configured to allow unkown sources for apks

**Already tried:**

1. Remounting /system RW
2. Using -selinux disabled (xposed however requires -selinux permissive)
3. Extracting the update-binary from xposed and run the script with su

**Current Status:**

If i try installing Xposed i get the following log messages from the emulator:

```
[  355.372965] type=1400 audit(1477138733.355:23): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=2796 comm="posed.installer" name="app_process" dev="mtdblock1" ino=7847 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  355.372984] type=1400 audit(1477138733.355:24): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  pid=2796 comm="posed.installer" path="/data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/cache/app_process" dev="mtdblock1" ino=7847 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  355.440354] type=1400 audit(1477138733.415:25): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2769 comm="posed.installer" name="app_process" dev="mtdblock0" ino=96 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  355.440410] type=1400 audit(1477138733.415:26): avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=2769 comm="posed.installer" name="app_process" dev="mtdblock0" ino=96 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  355.440450] type=1400 audit(1477138733.415:27): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=2769 comm="posed.installer" path="/system/bin/app_process" dev="mtdblock0" ino=96 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  365.476143] type=1400 audit(1477138743.455:28): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=2805 comm="Thread-110" name="su" dev="mtdblock0" ino=972 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:su_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  365.476280] type=1400 audit(1477138743.455:29): avc:  denied  { read open } for  pid=2805 comm="Thread-110" name="su" dev="mtdblock0" ino=972 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:su_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
[  365.476371] type=1400 audit(1477138743.455:30): avc:  denied  { execute_no_trans } for  pid=2805 comm="Thread-110" path="/system/xbin/su" dev="mtdblock0" ino=972 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:su_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
```

**Status-Update:**

As i know for now, the image was not rooted properly. I rerooted the Image using the packaged su binary from SuperSU-2.78. I manipulated the system.img by mounting it to a folder on my linux machine and added su and daemonsu (basically su copied and renamed) to /system/xbin/ and changed permissions to 6755 for both files. Additionally for now i added 2 lines to the end of /etc/init.goldfish.sh

```
#remount /system rw
mount -o rw,remount /system

#start daemonsu as auto-daemon
/system/xbin/daemonsu --auto-daemon
```

After installing both Superuser.apk from SuperSU and a suitable Xposed-Version, Xposed initially installs but after reboot it leads to segfaults in libdvm.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally managed to get this working (requires older sdk version (pre November 2016)

SuperSU still required as told in the question above

**Kernel Image lower than version 3.10 (kernel-qemu or engine classic)**

1. Start emulator in verbose-mode
2. note the temporary file which is used to mount /system inside qemu
3. Install Xposed but Cancel reboot
4. Copy temporary system.img from /tmp/android-{username}/emulator-{random chars} to lets say your home directory
5. Shutdown emulator
6. Overwrite existing system.img with the one from your home directory
7. Start Emulator again
8. Xposed should now be operating

**Kernel Version 3.10+ (kernel-ranchu or real sandboxed emulator)**

Unfortunatly there is currently no known way of modifying the system.img from within the ranchu-emulator, ranchu seems to block every write-operation.
The blocked operations let the system think, that the partition is broken, so the system remounts the partition readonly as a safty fallback.

*Two found work-arounds:*

1.) Use parameter -engine classic when starting the emulator (therefore forcing kernel-qemu) you can use the steps above to do your changes

2.) Use a kernel-image lower version 3.10 to avoid emulator ranchu. You can use the steps above and after your changes have been applied use the previous kernel-image again